# "Cannot find name '$'" after downloading project from stackblitz

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to build a website using [materializecss's carousel component](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html). I successfully did it on [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qze83y) and then tried to export it to my computer, but I ran into some issues.

Steps to reproduce :
Export project
Unzip

```
npm install  
ng serve -o
```

That produces the error ["cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEnLM.png).
I installed it using `npm install --save @angular-devkit/core`, and then tried to run the project again, this time getting the following error :
[Error message "Cannot find name '$'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnjUK.png)

I'm new to Angular so I might be missing something very obvious here, but from what I gathered, that must be an issue with the import of jquery. 
I thought importing via link in my index.html was enough, but I've had to also add all the links in the "external resources" on stackblitz to make it work.
I would guess that this is the import part that was not correctly added to the project I downloaded, but then how and where do I have to add the import on my local project?

```html
<head>

<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <my-app>loading</my-app>
</body>
```